# res.redirect is not a function in node js request method

Tags: node.js, express

I have used Request npm to send HTTP request using node js. once request method is call I need to redirect to other page but its not working.

```
request({
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionid
                }, 
                    uri: 'http://localhost:8888/SuiteCRM/api/v8/modules/Contacts',
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                }, function (err, res, body) {
                    if (!err) {
                         req.flash('success', 'User Successfully added...');
                        return  res.redirect('/crm');
                         //next();
                    } else {
                          console.log(err);
                    }
            });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `res` in `function (err, res, body) {` to some other name like `response` like `function (err, response, body) {`.

The issue is the express response object `res` gets overidden by the request's `response` object res if you keep the same name.

Comment: This must be it

Comment: Its not working getting same error.
response.redirect is not a function.

Comment: you need to call `res.redirect` not `response.redirect` while `response` would be the `request`'s response object.